# How do I use NSPageController on storyboard?

Tags: macos, xcode7, nsviewcontroller, nsstoryboard

On the storyboard when I try to add a **NSPageController**, it comes out with it's own view.

When I want to use a split view i can add a `NSSplitViewController` or just a split view. I prefer to use the SplitView inside a `NSViewController`.

Is there anyway I can use a `NSPageController` inside the `NSViewController` and then choose a subview to be my `NSPageController` content? Storyboard just won't allow me to put a PageController inside a View Controller. Any ideas?